# Classes Generics: Error not understandable

Tags: typescript

I have the example in a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-snowflake-kdpnl4?file=/src/Operation.ts:609-622). You will find the class in the file Operation.ts.

I made the class "Operation" to handle operations made on an object like a rectangle.
There are several types of operations ("move", "rotate", ...) and for every operation-type there is a different type of operation (move: [number, number], rotate: number, ...).
So I gave the class a generic that extends the types of operations. In the class I defined the _type: T and the _operation: OperationMap[T] to have the right operation of every operationType.

When the Operation has been executed I want to save the operationData. (like beforeState and afterState) Also I want to reverse the Data. (negate the move, rotation operationData)

At this point it comes to to two Errors I do not understand. I checked this._type for its type so Typescript should know which type T is and therefore also know the type of operationData and reversedOperationData.

I think I don't understand something here about typescript but after looking around I havent found an anwser that I understood. I'd be very thankful for any help.

```
type operationTypes = "move" | "rotate" | "rename";

type operationsMap = {
  move: [number, number];
  rotate: number;
  rename: string;
};

type operationsDataMap = {
  move: [number, number];
  rotate: number;
  rename: [string, string]; // before, after
};

export class Operation<T extends operationTypes> {
  _type: T;
  _operation: operationsMap[T];
  _operationData: operationsDataMap[T] | null = null;
  _ReversedOperationData: operationsDataMap[T] | null = null;

  constructor(type: T, operation: operationsMap[T]) {
    this._type = type;
    this._operation = operation;
  }

  set operationData(operationData: operationsDataMap[T]) {
    this._operationData = operationData;
    if (this._type === "move") {
      this._ReversedOperationData = [-operationData[0], -operationData[1]]; // The Problem is here
    }
    if (this._type === "rotate") {
      // reversed rotation
    }
    if (this._type === "move") {
      // reversed renaming
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that TS can't do if/else or switch/case control flow analysis with generics (see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for a related feature request).  For control flow you need a discriminated union (and classes can't be unions, so this is not a good avenue to pursue). For generics you need a single block of code that handles all cases.  This latter approach is shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbylbN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz,
that already helped out a lot and makes me understand why it doesnt work and what can be a workaround. Thank you alot!
I had one more Issue where I didnt know if it is possible.
I have a second class CompoundOperation which holds several Operations. I want to give the constructor and array of raw operation data and it will save them as an Operation in an array. The problem is how can I define a parameter of type array but not loose the combination of type and operation?
I add the code to my original post

Comment: Please don’t expand the scope of the question in response to my comment.  The goal was to find out if it addressed the question as asked.  If it did, then I’ll write up a full answer post. Follow-up questions should ideally be posted as their own posts.  Could you please undo your edit and I’ll answer?

Comment: @jcalz alright, no problem. I will open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript can't use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  When you check `(this._type === "move")`, the type of `this._type` is narrowed, but `K` (renaming from `T`, since `K` is more conventional for keylike types) stubbornly stays the same.  So then the compiler has no idea that `OperationsDataMap[K]` (again, renaming to be conventional; custom type names should be UpperCamelCase and not lowerCamelCase) will be specifically of type `[number, number]` and therefore it doesn't compile.

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) to support affecting generic type parameters via control flow analysis, but for now it's not part of the language.  Generic type parameters and `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` control flow don't play nicely together.

---

If you want to use generics and have the compiler follow your logic, you need to write things so that there's only one case that works for all possibilities.  TypeScript *can* recognize when you use a generic key to index into an object.  That is, if you have an object `obj` of type `Obj` and a key `k` of generic type `K`, then `obj[k]` will be seen as the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Obj[K]`.  If our object's type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of *functions*, then we can refactor `if`/`else` blocks to the bodies of these functions.  This technique is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Here's one way to do it:

```
set operationData(operationData: OperationsDataMap[K]) {
  this._operationData = operationData;
  const rev: { [K in OperationTypes]: (x: OperationsDataMap[K]) => OperationsDataMap[K] } = {
    move: (x) => [-x[0], -x[1]], 
    rotate: x => -x, // I guessed
    rename: x => [x[1], x[0]] // I guessed
  }
  this._ReversedOperationData = rev[this._type](this._operationData);
}
```

So here we have `rev`, an object specifically [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) to be a mapped type over `OperationTypes`, the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `K`.  Each property is a function from `OperationsDataMap[K]` to itself, and the compiler validates the body of each function accordingly.  Then you can just call `rev[this._type](this._operationData)` and it works, because `rev[this.type]` is given the type `(x: OperationsDataMap[K]) => OperationsDataMap[K]`, and so when you pass it `this._operationData` of type `OperationsDataMap[K]`, you get an `OperationsDataMap[K]` out.  Which is acceptable to assign to `this._ReversedOperationData`.

Hooray.

---

Such refactoring isn't always easy or even possible.  It only works if you are switching on some keylike value (so that you can index into an object with it), and it's only easy if the existing types are already "basic" enough so that the object can be written as a mapped type over these existing types directly.  Otherwise you need to employ the full machinery as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, which can sometimes be daunting for people.

In cases where it's not easy or not possible, you can always just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to prevent the compiler from complaining:

```
if (this._type === "move") {
  const o = operationData as [number, number];
  this._ReversedOperationData = [-o[0], -o[1]] as OperationsDataMap[K]
}
```

That is equivalent to turning type checking off and taking the burden of verifying type safety off of the compiler and onto yourself. If you prefer expedience to compiler-verified type safety, that might be an approach to take.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYBLA9gOwCrggZygF4oAiAWzQDcISoAfU+NYZG+xiDRMmgbgCh+oSLATJ0GPAFlEYIlADe-KFArUAXFADaGAK5kARhHgAaKHsPGAugJVMWwCJotH4tqPE7cnUPMHgoGADmAgC+AkK4osbimHgAIsiIMnLESipqPjr6rmYu1u72rM45xoVePJpafgHBZjWBQTZQAPQtUEYAZmieZoidjvD84YL8EAAeYD3AUADGADaIeARwMaiYADwA0lATjhgAJiti69i4eAB8ispQAPrCPlvut2gnEpqrSKfSslpbNjcXm9MIkWB9gZJQclfv92Hp5vN5PD5s8AEoQajwPAQA6fWIYKHgtYSBJJFJ-Kxw3QIpHUlGCFSzOL+XSzYA9AAUD00WzMr2JmCJXxJ5P+AEprioVMAABYoPAAOnuUWID3c0rliqBAow8n5wsw7lCDN8EBm+vxUI5FtOhOiBshZJhVgl6SlsvlSptEiheohUPVc2ZHgxmgU2h2gXt+JwkDwVk0HPGQvxpJYopdRCueO+UIzUFC8jdUtUVB8SYlhCuWgAtOMtAAGKxmOtaACMVmbrRaNxLRUcmnGWagdbMbSgAHc0NSDlAZYhqB0IJxzChZtBuvAoCBp1B2VAwLoZhP545MXPjBBe1LPFxKlAh1XtPWO2Z603KeOpzO5wvoEYVwwNcNx6bdd33Q9j1PDFjAvTxr2NEsPS1dFMWxXF-SSeRPEoLRkKVB4rC5TUvUwlgxSNE1sXNMjEAAJmtWiU1zJ0wApV1r3w7UHV9YhvRBJJAxQTooGIz1lREQgpNITISA4ktGWDNA-R1X0lm0fJTHMUp4ABBS9xI25UOMdCcx9LDiFrNBGy7GtrI7Sl1LMuI82dBDr2E0SuIeIhpJIfsaHkhTxxwkycQ8Zh8XcktPLErUfKk4hyDLOTJWC9pQqxcLb24RpooLYYgA)

Answer (score 0):

As per Your code , directly typescript can't do this type of operation using if/else or switch, but we can do using `as` and also your error will be resolved

```js
type operationTypes = "move" | "rotate" | "rename";

type operationsMap = {
  move: [number, number];
  rotate: number;
  rename: string;
};

type operationsDataMap = {
  move: [number, number];
  rotate: number;
  rename: [string, string]; // before, after
};

export class Operation<T extends operationTypes> {
  _type: T;
  _operation: operationsMap[T];
  _operationData: operationsDataMap[T] | null = null;
  _ReversedOperationData: operationsDataMap[T] | null = null;

  constructor(type: T, operation: operationsMap[T]) {
    this._type = type;
    this._operation = operation;
  }

  set operationData(operationData: operationsDataMap[T]) {
    this._operationData = operationData;
    if (this._type === "move") {
        const Data = this._operationData as operationsDataMap['move']
        this._ReversedOperationData = [Data[0], Data[1]] as operationsDataMap[T];
    }
    if (this._type === "rotate") {
      // reversed rotation
      const Data = this._operationData as operationsDataMap['rotate']
        this._ReversedOperationData = Data as operationsDataMap[T];
    }
    if (this._type === "rename") {
      // reversed renaming
      const Data = this._operationData as operationsDataMap['rename']
      this._ReversedOperationData = Data as operationsDataMap[T];
    }
  }
}

const operationMethod = new Operation('rotate' , 1);

operationMethod.operationData
```