# Different connected generic types in an array

Tags: typescript

This is a follow up question [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77360701/classes-generics-error-not-understandable).

I have a second class CompoundOperation which holds several raw operation's. I want to give the constructor an array of raw operation data and it will save them in an array of raw operations. The problem is: how can I define a parameter of type array, but not lose the combination of type and operation?

```
type OperationTypes = "move" | "rotate" | "rename";

type OperationsMap = {
  move: [number, number];
  rotate: number;
  rename: string;
};

type OperationRaw<K extends OperationTypes> = {
  type: K;
  operation: OperationsMap[K];
};

export class CompoundOperation {
  _operations: OperationRaw<OperationTypes>[];

  constructor(operations: OperationRaw<OperationTypes>[]) {
    this._operations = operations
  }
}

new CompoundOperation([{type: "move", operation: "Default"}]) // this shouldnt be possible
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] the question to include your [mre] here, not just in the other question. Ideally you'd remove anything unnecessary (such as implementation of the other stuff, it can just be declarations). ② You can make your constructor argument a *discriminated union* as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/wjpabm). The `map` can't be verified though.  That kind of thing is going to require existential types to write properly, and that might be overkill for your needs.  And I consider that out of scope here anyway, since your problem is with the constructor call, not your (invalid) implementation.

Comment: Does the prev comment ② fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full explanation as an answer.  (as long as you address ① also).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it does, thank you very much and I tried to further shrink down the code to give a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the type `OperationRaw<OperationTypes>` is not what you want to express.  That becomes

```
type Oops = OperationRaw<OperationTypes>;
/* type Oops = {
    type: "move" | "rotate" | "rename";
    operation: string | number | [number, number];
} */
```

which allows those mismatching properties.  Really what you want to do is *distribute* the `OperationRaw<K>` type function across [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `K`.

This can be done a number of ways... one is to write a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).  If you have a type function `F<K>` where `K` is keylike and you want to distribute across unions in `K`, you can write `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`.  That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  So if `K` is `"k1" | "k2" | "k3"`, then that type expands to `{k1: F<"k1">; k2: F<"k2">; k3: F<"k3">}["k1" | "k2" | "k3"}` and finally `F<"k1"> | F<"k2"> | F<"k3">` as desired, instead of the `F<"k1" | "k2" | "k3">` you'd get if you just plugged `K` in to `F` directly.

For your code that looks like

```
type SomeOperationRaw = { [K in OperationTypes]: OperationRaw<K> }[OperationTypes];
// type SomeOperationRaw = OperationRaw<"move"> | OperationRaw<"rotate"> | OperationRaw<"rename">

/* type SomeOperationRaw = {
    type: "move";
    operation: [number, number];
   } | {
    type: "rotate";
    operation: number;
   } | {
    type: "rename";
    operation: string;
   } */
```

That's now a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `type` property can be used to distinguish which union member it is.

---

Now you can write your `CompoundOperation` class using `SomeOperationRaw`:

```
export class CompoundOperation {
  _operations: SomeOperationRaw[];

  constructor(operations: SomeOperationRaw[]) {
    this._operations = operations
  }
}
```

And now you get the error you expected:

```
new CompoundOperation([
  { type: "move", operation: [0, 0] }, // okay
  { type: "move", operation: "Default" }, // error
  { type: "rename", operation: "Default" } // okay
]) // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYBLA9gOwCrggZygF4oAiAWzQDcISoAfU+NYZG+xiDRMmgbgCh+oSLATJ0GPAFlEYIlADe-KFArUAXFADaGAK5kARhHgAaKHsPGAugJVMWwCJotH4tqPE7cnUPMHgoGADmAgC+AkK4osbimABKiADuADwA0lAQAB6OGAAmBHAxqJg4kHgAfPJKKsI+qe5oYsUYmoVIzdKyWqk2-OGCtbCNBMRtsRgJKWPNpfjlAgD0AFRQgzDDVcoqq7ia5FRsDCT2rLRHnlw8JO4qjUUSmn4Bwewuxuw6+q5mb-C9oVAlgsBlEAMpoHjTCSTKradKBaLtCSzPBWVpNaFJNKVUJaKElXCoxYLHYicGQjHxJLyfETLH7agkSoMWmTZLHZinZmI8Zs45eK7lfjLUnQckQVnU4jVba1PZqPhbW6UlraX4-L7WG4Ahgymq7RicxzXJVQO5IzDOTVuJU6xSmuUcS6K7ZmlWPfyBEK2wHA-hZMBoeDAKAAYwANog8AQAMIQwO6PK0+0qAD65vGeE04sliS0vS2ocwT10oeAQYAFBmOtmIRKVZN8wBKFOygAWKDwADp0yqRm77sWtqE+oIMBBElA42QE0mVRWtFsFKL5QcSGZqw9tAAGMzbqxQUJmBYktAAa0QICXK9ICvXA4tqpIABEIAAzRC6cPAWhHqAnjJ4CYeBr0dflnXvTdLVIV8Py-H9D3-U8LyvKwWwA4xgIAQiAA)